# Java Version check in Command Prompt

Tags: java, version

I am using a 32 bit windows 7 OS and I have installed JDK 8 as it was the only available JDK version for a 32 bit system. I have also given the path in the environment variables. But, when I am trying to check the java version in the command prompt typing java --version, I am getting a fatal error.

Comment: please provide the full output you get

Comment: It's only one dash: `java -version`,  NOT two dashes: `java --version`. Two dashes with generate a `fatal exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check if your path variable is set correctly. It should point to the ...\bin\ directory where the 'java.exe' is located. Because thats whats called with 'java --version'.